# MVC View from different controller

Tags: model-view-controller, routes, view

Ok, I'm learning MVC because of my work, it's entirely new to me but I need to get better.
I'm work in a project that have two different layouts, same information and same database, i just need to alternate between the two layouts.
I have a `HomeController(first layout)` and `HomeControllerMag(second layout)` that contains the same methods, I just added a suffix 'Mag' for the second controller.
In the index of the first controller I need to call the index of the second controller and vice versa.
The configuration of the `'RouteConfig.cs'` looks very simple but it's just not working.
In the first home view I'm using an 'a' tag:
 `<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("HomeMag")" class="nav-brand"></a>`

HomeMag is the name of the route for the second controller.

```
//first template routes ======================================

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Home",
                url: "",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Category",
                url: "{CategoryName}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "CategoryPostList",
                    categoryName = UrlParameter.Optional
                });

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "PostDetail",
                url: "{CategoryName}/{SeoLink}/{ID}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "PostDetail",
                    ID = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    categoryName = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    seoLink = UrlParameter.Optional
                });

            //second template routes =========================================
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "/HomeMag",
                url: "HomeMag",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "HomeMag",
                    action = "IndexMag"
                });

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "CategoryMag",
                url: "{CategoryName}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "HomeMag",
                    action = "CategoryPostListMag",
                    categoryName = UrlParameter.Optional
                });

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "PostDetailMag",
                url: "{CategoryName}/{SeoLink}/{ID}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "HomeMag",
                    action = "PostDetailMag",
                    ID = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    categoryName = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    seoLink = UrlParameter.Optional
                });
```

The idea is to have a button in the view to alternate between the index's of the two home Controllers.
Please help, it is a very cool project and I want to put it in may portfolio.

I tried to config the routes for the second template.